# change string where find @username in php

Tags: php, html, regex

How to replace @username in a complete string where find.

Example:
Original string : `"Hello @mike and @max how are you";`

Expected result string  : `"Hello <a href="#">@mike</a> and <a href="#">@max</a> how are you'`

I am tried to use strpos and explode, but not got solution.

Please help any one! Thanks.

Comment: Show your code, what you have tried so far

Comment: Why do you need regexes? Take a look at `str_replace`.

Comment: well, apart from the fact that basic solutions with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) **and** explode/implode would be quite trivial, it should be noted that regexes would be a nice solution, too, because otherwise values for `@max` would also possibly be inserted into `@maximilian`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
$Output = preg_replace("/(\@\w+)/", "<a href='#'>$1</a>", $Original_String);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hVf

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the website reference too

Comment: Thank you very much @Andreas

Comment: No problem, you should thank @jitendrapurohit too. He corrected my mistake.

Comment: @flex If you found the answer correct you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$orig = "Hello @mike and @max how are you";
$arr = explode(" ", $orig);
$newArr = array();

foreach ($arr as $word) {
    $tmp = $word;
    if ($word[0] == '@') {
        $tmp = '<a href="#">'.$word.'</a>';
    }
    $newArr[] = $tmp;
}

$newStr = implode(" ", $newArr);
```

Comment: that fails for `<sometag>@max</sometag>` since there is no space - or perhaps names succeeded by a comma or point or something.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the function str_replace

You can read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$intro   = 'Hello';
$user    = 'Person';
$message = 'Hope your day is going well.';

$source = '@intro, @user!  @message';
$search = ['@intro','@user', '@message'];
$replace = [$intro, $user, $message];

$message = str_replace($search, $replace, $source);
var_dump($message);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? This is nothing what the OP asked for, or am I missing something?